# SourceBuffer causes MediaSource to fail if even one segment is missing

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing, media-source

I have:

```
const startVideoListener = eventName => {
  const mediaSource = new MediaSource()
  const src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)
  let sourceBuffer = null
  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs=vp9')
  })
  
  socket.on(eventName, function (chunk, id) {
    if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
      count++
      if (count === 5) return
      console.log({ count })
      sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk)
    }
  })
  return src
}
```

I have a stream that works when all segments come through. One I miss even a single segment (as shown with the 5th segment above) the video breaks and becomes completely unplayable.

Is this a constraint imposed by the format/codec or is there a way to recover from missing segments in a `SourceBuffer` or `MediaSource`?

I've tried to remove segments and several other things, but there isn't much context in the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer

Comment: Do you mean a full segment is missing - i.e. multiple network packets? It's not something that would be typical because of network connections so presumably some other issue?